# Downloading files from Document Library from the Name column - and avoiding the 'No Preview available page'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document, library, download, preview

I'm new here and this is my first post!

On my SharePoint site, I have quite a few files with the extension '.arc' in a document library (actually, thousands of them). These are dedicated files for a measurement system. They are also linked to a specific application, so they open in that if I double-click them in Explorer.

Well, within my SharePoint document library, my first issue is that I would like users to be able to click the filename in the Name column and for it to download directly in Edge. At the moment, it does not and SharePoint tries to open it in another tab, where I get the predictable "Hmm, looks like this has no preview" page. OK, I (or the users) can download it from there, but I would like to just click the name and for it to download. I have enabled the library-specific option to open in the client application and also the site-wide option to do the same. No effect. I always end up with the "Hmmm.." page.

My second issue is with Versions (with the same .arc files). If I view the versions of the file and click directly on the last modified date, a blank page is opened in a new tab. The URL behind the version link shows the link to the file, so if I right-click it, I can download it.

If I click on View, I get the properties page, where it shows me the filename. Clicking on this leads me to another blank page in a new tab.

Is there a way to resolve this in a more elegant manner? I would like my users to be able to "click and go".

But, do you know what (and what is frustrating me)? It *used* to work like this until a week or so ago. I clicked the ARC file in the document library and it instantly downloaded into my download folder. From the Versions page, clicking the date downloaded the file in the same way. I showed many users this and it was fine. Now I have the aforementioned situation - empty tabs and "Hmmm" pages when clicking.

This is all in Edge, Chrome is the same, as are InPrivate sessions.

Well, many thanks in advance if anyone can shed any light on this - any more information, just ask.

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, if you click on a document, the default behavior is to open the file you clicked on.

According to my understanding, such a prompt may be due to the file type, because usually the file will be opened directly.

We can set to open in the browser or open in the desktop application, but it will not download directly.
[image]

In addition, if you view the version history, you can only view the latest version, and the previous version needs to be restored.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Something changed in the background. I came back to my computer on Monday morning, and mostly everything was back to normal - i.e. if I directly click on the version history date, the file downloads directly to my Downloads folder, instead of throwing open a new empty tab.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you find the answer, or have any updates, you could post here to share with us. :)